# How to filter out catch blocks

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch

I need to `return false` prevent logging if `SP.ServerException` has been thrown.
But in all other cases i need to do logging and `return false` too.

```
try
{
    folder = GetFolderByRelativeUrl(folderRelativePath);
}
catch (SP.ServerException serverEx)
{
    //if file is not found the logging is not need
    if (serverEx?.Message == "File not found")
    {
        return false;
    }
    //how i can go from here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //to there
    Log(ex.Message);
    return false;
}
```

I know the solution could be

```
try
{
    folder = GetFolderByRelativeUrl(folderRelativePath);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //if file is not found the logging is not need
    if (!(ex is SP.ServerException && ex?.Message == "File not found"))
    {
        Log(ex.Message);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?  It seems reasonable.  And I'd much prefer the explicit separate catch block for a special exception case to the type checking if statement.

Comment: I guess all is well with my code =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the `when` keyword:

```
try
{
    folder = GetFolderByRelativeUrl(folderRelativePath);
}
catch (SP.ServerException serverEx) when (serverEx.Message == "File not found")
{
   return false;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //to there
    Log(ex.Message);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted

Comment: never heard of `when`  before +1

Comment: it's a feature from C# 6

Answer (score 2):

In c# 6, you can filter exceptions :

```
catch (SP.ServerException ex ) when (ex.Message == "File not found")
```